# Selenium Python: How to scroll a div

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I need to flip through a number of pages of a list on the left side of the page [here](https://2gis.ru/moscow/search/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%20/tab/geo?queryState=center%2F37.644653%2C55.827805%2Fzoom%2F12). To do that firstly I need to scroll down a specific div section and then to click on the `next` button. But the scrolling works perfect in one case (`url_ok`) and doesn't work in another (`url_trouble`). Don't have any ideas why.
The code I'm testing:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driverPath = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driverPath)   

url_trouble = 'https://2gis.ru/moscow/search/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%20/tab/geo?queryState=center%2F37.644653%2C55.827709%2Fzoom%2F12'   

url_ok = 'https://2gis.ru/moscow/search/%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%20/tab/firms?queryState=center%2F37.644653%2C55.827805%2Fzoom%2F12'


def click(url, driver):
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()
    time.sleep(5)
    next_link_data = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.pagination__arrow._right")
    next_link_data.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    next_link_data.click()

click(url_trouble, driver) # it doesn't work
click(url_ok, driver) # it works
```

So the question is how to scroll the `url_trouble` to the bottom?

Thanks a lot for advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because i guess two "div.pagination__arrow._right" are in page.

> use more specific selector
>   try this one  --> **"#module-1-13-1-1-2-2 > div.pagination__arrow._right"**
>   in

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#module-1-13-1-1-2-2 > div.pagination__arrow._right")
```